# Missing Android trusted certificates

Tags: android, ssl, certificate, trusted-root-certificates, adb

I wanted to setup Burp Suite to use it as a proxy in order to debug an app that I am currently developing. Since I need to use HTTPS too, I followed this [guide](https://blog.ropnop.com/configuring-burp-suite-with-android-nougat/#installburpcaasasystemleveltrustedca) to install a root trusted CA certificate.

Basically, after I have created a compatible certificate (in the form of `<hash>.0`) I pushed it to the mobile in `/sdcard` and executed the following commands in an `adb shell`:

```
$ su
# mount -o rw,remount /system
# mv /sdcard/<hash>.0 /system/etc/security/cacerts/
# chmod 644 /system/etc/security/cacerts/<hash>.0
# chgrp root /system/etc/security/cacerts/<hash>.0
```

Then I rebooted the mobile with `adb reboot`.

After reboot, I don't see any trusted credential anymore from Settings->Security->Trusted credentials: both system and user listings are completely empty, all the certificates that previously could be seen there are now gone. Now apps cannot connect to the internet anymore, Chrome for example gives always a `NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID` error. Firefox instead seems to be the only app which can connect to the internet.

I have checked with `adb` and the certificates are still there in `/system/etc/security/cacerts/`, with permissions which seem to be correct (644, owned by root:root).

Does anybody have some clue about what could have happened and how I can try to make Android see the certificates again?

Comment: How did you create the hash?

Comment: BTW: Firefox doesn't use the system's certificate store but its own, that is why it is not afflicted.